# Get true object type in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, telerik, javascript-objects, typeof

The screenshot below shows the highlighted JavaScript object being of type `Telerik.Web.UI.Grid`.

[image: True Object Type in JavaScript]

**Question** : What would be the right JavaScript code to get the true type of  JavaScript object `$telerik.radControls[6]`? I need to dynamically determine  the true type at runtime in JavaScript and then do something based on the true type.

I tried the code below, but typeof always returns `object`.

```
if (typeof $telerik.radControls[6] === "Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid") {
   //do something
} else if(typeof $telerik.radControls[6] === "Telerik.Web.UI.RadSearchBox") {
 //do something
} else if (typeof $telerik.radControls[6] === "Telerik.Web.UI.RadTreeView") {
 //do something
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

I tried some suggestions mentioned under comments, but I get not available when I use `instanceof`  as in screen show below.

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

I found an interesting fact when using `instanceof` to determine the true type of a JavaScript object. The code below will not work always. It will only work if there is already an object of type `Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid` i.e. a constructor for the object type we are checking has been called. I got the following error when no object of `Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid` had been instantiated.

> Uncaught TypeError: Expecting a function in instanceof check, but got undefined

**Unsafe Code that will work only if the object type exists**

```
if (x instance of Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid) {
   //do something
}
```

However, when I used code like below then it will not throw an error even when no object of `Telerik.Web.UI.RaGrid` type has been instantiated.

**Safe Code that will always work i.e. not throw an error**

```
if (typeof Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid !== "undefined && x instance of Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid) {
   //do something
}
```

Comment: `if ($telerik.radControls[6] instanceof Telerik.Web.UI.Grid) {...` assuming that `Telerik.Web.UI.Grid` is the constructor function that holds the prototype of the object.

Comment: You will have to check `instanceOf`

Comment: @squint, It says `not available` when I pasted `$telerik.radControls[6] instanceof Telerik.Web.UI.Grid` in Chrome's watch window.

Comment: Try `$telerik.radControls[6].constructor.name`

Comment: @squint, I have pasted the screenshot using your code under `UPDATE 1`.

Comment: @andr, It gives asn empty string. However, after drilling through object hierarchy I found `$telerik.radControls[6].constructor.getName()` gives the name of true object type. But not sure if this is the right code that will work across modern browsers.

Comment: @Sunil right, this is compatible only with Chrome and Firefox. Try `$telerik.radControls[6].constructor.toString().match(/function (\w*)/)[1];`

Comment: @andr, The expression you mentioned returns an empty string. I would think there would be an easy way to determine the true object type in JavaScript.

Comment: I had copied and pasted a modified version of your code. It looks like you want `RadGrid` instead of `Grid`. So `$telerik.radControls[6] instanceof Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid`

Comment: @squint, Sorry I don't know how I missed that part and didn't notice that `Rad` was missing. It works. Can you please post this as answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `instanceof` operator will give you a boolean result telling you if its left operand, an object, has the `.prototype` of the right operand, a function, in its prototype chain.

So assuming `Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid` is the constructor function, you can do this:

```
$telerik.radControls[6] instanceof Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid
```